# Where do I find glass to smith with?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have ran around this game world for 100+ hours and I have never seen raw glass. Am I missing it? Or is there something special that happens when I take the skill to craft glass? I have not taken it because I have never seen glass.

Comment: To make Glass armor you need Malachite ore. It's not acutely glass. Just imagine how weak that armor would be :L

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Glass items are made from [Refined Malachite](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Refined_Malachite) which is in turn made by smelting 2 [Malachite Ores](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Malachite_Ore).

### Malachite Ore can be found:

> - 7 veins in Steamscorch Mine, directly Northeast of Kynesgrove.
> - 2 veins (along with 2 Ebony Ore veins) at the top of Throat of the World.
> - 4 at Labyrinthian Thoroughfare (Hjaalmarch)
> - 3 at Labyrinthian, Tribune
> - 2 centered at 150 ft NE of Kynesgrove
> - 1 at The Brinehammer Below Deck (The Pale)

### Refined Malachite can be found:

> - 3 centered at 180 ft NE of Kynesgrove
> - 2 at Swindler's Den (Whiterun Hold)
> - 1 at Saarthal Excavation (Winterhold)
> - 1 at Understone Keep (Markarth)
> - Sold by blacksmiths and general goods merchants starting at level 18 (20?)

Answer (score 6):

"Glass" forged items are actually made from a green metal named Malachite.  It's not actually glass.  So once you take the perk, you can create items based on Malachite.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're referring to the Glass Smithing perk in the Smithing tree.

While I haven't taken that perk myself, according to [UESPWiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forge#Glass_Smithing), none of the glass pieces take glass as a raw material. They all tend to take some combination of leather, leather strips, malachite, and moonstone.

Answer (score 0):

No. The actual 360 version says nothing about making just glass. Glass weapons and armor can be made from refined malachite, but there is no glass with which to make furniture from. In the hearthfire DLC, the work bench asks for glass to build items for your house, but none of the forgible or smelting options are just glass. Even though there are thousands of items to loot and buy, there is no glass.

Answer (score -2):

I play on the Nintendo Switch but it seems that on this version you can buy glass and straw from places like the River Wood Trader.

Answer (score -5):

Try looking in caves and stuff like that.